# XFS increase size

Tags: rhel, xfs

How to increase data size at the expense of the other disk.
xfs_growfs without param [from,to] increase.

```
 /dev/sda8       45695376 36341884   9353492  80% /data
 Disk /dev/sda: 128 GB
 Disk /dev/sdb: 320 GB
```

Need for sda8 increase size from /dev/sdb with save data on "/data"

Answer (score 2):

1. Create LVM volume group on sdb.
2. Create logical volume with XFS in the volume group.
3. Copy your data.
4. Verify your data is in good condition on the new filesystem.
5. Add sda8 to the volume group.
6. Extend logical volume to span the new size.
7. Run xfs_growfs on the XFS.